# Use Java to find a File within a directory using only a Name

Tags: java, search, directory

I'm trying to write this script that takes an Excel sheet, gets all the names of files from the cells, and moves each of those files to a specific folder. I've already got most of the code done, I just need to be able to search for each file in the source directory using just its title. Another problem is that I'm searching for multiple file types (.txt, .repos, .xlsx, .xls, .pdf, and some files don't have extensions), I only can search by the file name without the extension.

In my findAndMoveFiles method, I've got an ArrayList of each File and a Guava Multimap of XSSFCells to Strings (a cell is one cell from the Excel file and a String is the name of the folder it needs to go into, one to many relationship) as parameters. What I've got right now for the method is this.

```
public static void findAndMoveFiles(List<File> files, Multimap<XSSFCell, String> innerCells) {
    // For each file, get its values (folders), and put that file in each of those folders
    for (XSSFCell cell : innerCells.keySet()) {
        // find the file in the master directory
        //Finder f = new Finder();
        //if (f.canBeFound(FOLDER, cell.getStringCellValue())) {
            File file = find(FOLDER, cell.getStringCellValue());
            //System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
            //List<String> values = new ArrayList(innerCells.get(cell));
            /*for (String folder : values) {
                File copy = file;
                if (copy != null) {
                    System.out.println(folder);
                    System.out.println(copy.getAbsolutePath());
                    if (copy.renameTo(new File("C:\\strobell\\" + folder + "\\" + copy.getAbsolutePath()))) {
                        System.out.println(copy.getName() + " has been moved successfully.");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(copy.getName() + " has failed to move.");
                    }
                }
            }*/
        //}
    }
}

public static File find(File dir, String fileName) {
    String files = "";
    File[] listOfFiles = dir.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            files = listOfFiles[i].getAbsolutePath();
            if (files.equals(fileName)) {
                return listOfFiles[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I commented out parts because it wasn't working. I was getting NullPointerExceptions because some files were being returned as null. I know that it's returning null, but each file should be found.

If there are any 3rd party libraries that can do this, that would be amazing, I've been racking my brain on how to do this properly.

Comment: Are the file paths in the excel cells absolute? Can you post a print of the `dir.listFiles()` and all `cell.getStringCellValue()`-s so that we can compare and think of a solution?

Comment: try by trimming file name, just an imaginary guess :)

Comment: Milan, the Excel cells are just like this "fileName". They have no extensions or paths. I have all the files in a folder in my src folder for the project in Eclipse though.

Comment: "Questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. "

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
File[] listOfFiles = dir.listFiles();
```

use

```
File[] listOfFiles = dir.list(new FileNameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        if( /* code to check if file name is ok */ ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}););
```

Then you can code your logic on the file names in the condition.